# Interspersing text with enumerated items

Tags: indentation, enumerate, enumitem

I would like to intersperse my text with some shaded assignments for the reader to try to do. I'd also like to enumerate these with numbers to keep track of them.  My current code is as follows, but I don't like the indent that occurs as part of the enumerate package. I know I can reduce it using enumitem and \setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}, but I don't quite like that either.  It doesn't completely remove the enumerate.

I'd really like a way of numbering a series of assignments interspersed in the text, without interrupting the layout of the surrounding text.
Any thoughts?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{shaded}
\item This is an assigment.
\end{shaded}

\Blindtext

\begin{shaded}
\item This is a second assignment.
\end{shaded}
\Blindtext
\begin{shaded}
\item This is a third assignment
\end{shaded}
\end{enumerate}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: I define an `assignment` environment, based on the `snugshade*` environment from `framed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray!35!}
\newcounter{assignment}
\newenvironment{assignment}{%
\refstepcounter{assignment}\setlength\OuterFrameSep{2pt plus 1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{5pt}\begin{snugshade*}\hspace*{-\dimexpr\labelsep+\fboxsep\relax}\textbf{\theassignment.}}%
{\end{snugshade*}}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext[2][1]
\begin{assignment}
This is an assigment. \label{ass-a}
\end{assignment}

\begin{assignment}
This is an assignment. This is an assignment. This is an assignment. This is an assignment.
\end{assignment}

\Blindtext[1][1]
\begin{assignment}
This is another assignment,  different from assignment \ref{ass-a}. 
\end{assignment}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]